# "Running this experiment in environment A gives you a different result than running it environment B"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

I was trying to write a sentence explaining that two different results can be observed from the same experiment conducted in two different environments.

I initially wrote:

> Running this experiment in environment A gives you a different result than running it environment

However it doesn't sound right for some reason. I tweaked it slightly to:

> Running this experiment in environment A gives you a different result than the result from running it environment B

It sounds better but too wordy. I wonder what is the correct way to say this?

Answer (score 1):

An improvement would be: **Running/conducting this experiment in environment A gives/produces a different result from that in environment B.**